# Mapping libraries modelsim

Tags: tcl, vhdl, modelsim

I am trying to map libraries using a do file in ModelSim PE 10.4a and am having trouble making them local to the project. E.g. I don't want to hard-code the commands for changing directories to compile sources into a working directory there, but I would be okay with providing a path to the .do/.tcl file that would define a static library or something. For Xilinx core libs, the compiled sources don't move and I don't need to recompile so I can just have a hard mapping. However, I am developing some stuff for a project and want a nice way to map libraries and compile them. For unit tests, I don't mind using this hard-coded method. However, for projects where these locations may change or the directories apart from my libs may be far, what is a better way of doing what I have done below?

Below is how I compile my library (do_map_lfsr.do)

```
# 0) Create work directory for modelsim
vlib LFSR_lib

# 2) Compile files in use order
#vcom -93 -work work src/*.vhd
vcom -93 -work LFSR_lib GaloisLfsrBody.vhd
vcom -93 -work LFSR_lib LfsrPack.vhd
```

Below is the method I use to run this do file from the location of my testbench

```
# 1a) map/compile libs
# trying to find better way to do this
cd ../
do do_map_lfsr.do
cd unit_test/
vmap -modelsim_quiet LFSR_lib ../LFSR_lib
```

Is there a fancy way of finding and recompiling my libraries using .do/.tcl files and then mapping them for my development outside unit tests? Is there a way of defining a static library or something that doesn't disappear when I change directories?

Answer (score 0):

For finding the files, the [Tcllib `find` command](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html#12) (in the fileutil package) should be very useful.

```tcl
package require fileutil

proc needsRecompiling {name} {
    return [expr {[file extension $name] in {.do .tcl}}]
}

foreach filename [fileutil::find . needsRecompiling] {
    if {[file extension $filename] eq ".do"} {
        # Process the .do file here
    } else {
        # Process the .tcl file here
    }
}
```

Of course, that assumes that you can just process each file independently; the order of listing isn't guaranteed (and likely depends on the order in the underlying directory node in the filesystem and things like that). If you need to do more complex things like matching files with different extensions, you'll need to write more code.